# "Error in scan" while reading a large file in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a large file of about 5,00,000 rows and 1000 columns. I am trying to read it in R as follows:

```
> tab5rows <- read.delim("file_name.txt", header=TRUE,nrows=5)
> classes <- sapply(tab5rows, class)
> data <- read.delim("file_name.txt",  header=TRUE,nrows=500000,colClasses=classes,comment.char="")
```

But on doing the last line, I get the following error.

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '0,00'
```

Can anyone help me know how do i resolve this? I cannot open my file in notepad or excel as it is very large. How can I resolve this from R ?

Your help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read it as `character`, search for those "," values and replace them. Possibly "," was used as a decimal seperator? On a Windows system I recommend Notepad++ for opening large text files.

Comment: @Pooja: @Roland is on to something. Try supplying `dec=','` to `read.delim`.

Comment: @Roland I replaced all the "," by "." and tried it again. I still get the same error.. Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '0.00' can u tell me how do i read it as a character ?

Comment: @mplourde I tried that as well. It still gives me the error..

Comment: @Pooja you're going to have to change `classes` so the datatype corresponding to that column is `numeric`, not `integer`. Then @Roland's or my suggestion will probably work for you.

Comment: @mplourde i am sorry to ask this minor thing again. But I am still into learning R. Can you help me know how do i specify the column as numeric ? How do I change it in my code ?

Comment: You should be able to apply arguments as defined in `?read.table` to your `read.delim` call to specify numeric, rather than integer, data. In the long run, I strongly recommend using `scan` or `read.table` over `read.delim` . It takes a little while to learn the various arguments, but it's a more flexible approach.

Comment: @Pooja You might get away with leaving the `colClasses` argument out of your call to `read.delim` and let R figure out the datatypes for you---otherwise, you could do `classes <- ifelse(classes == 'integer', 'numeric', classes)`

Comment: With 5 M rows you'll want the performance gain from using `colClasses`.

Comment: We should really create a community wiki for this type of question. The answer is almost always a dupe of about 1-5 different situations.

Comment: You might also want to get an editor that *can* open files like this. Or learn to use Unix command-line tools such as grep and awk to rapidly inspect text files - get them for Windows via cygwin.

Comment: @Spacedman I prefer MinGW over Cygwin. And for rapid inspection I like `tail` and `head`, or `vim` if you want to open it.

Comment: @Paul ...open it? why would you ever want to close it?? :p